# Custom Model Binder for specific property in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

Sometimes I need to bind datetime property without seconds in an ASP.NET Core controller. To achieve this, I created a custom `JsonConverter` and it works fine when this model used in the action method expects `application/json`.

```
public class TestDataModel
{
     [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeWithoutSecondsConverter))]
     public DateTime DateToTest { get; set; }
}

public class DateTimeWithoutSecondsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value != null)
        {
            return ((DateTime)reader.Value).ToDateTimeWithoutSeconds();
        }

        return existingValue;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?);
    }
}
```

But when the same model used in get action method, the `JsonConverter` is not working anymore. For that case I can create custom `IModelBinder`. Something like this

```
public class TestDataModel
{
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DateWithoutSecondsModelBinder))]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeWithoutSecondsConverter))]
    public DateTime DateToTest { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` in project where that model is defined. Is it possible to achieve this without `ModelBinder` attribute?

One of my idea is to use `IModelBinderProvider` for this. Something like this

```
public class DateWithoutSecondsModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(DateTime) || context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            //how to check if property has [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeWithoutSecondsConverter))] attribute
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(DateWithoutSecondsModelBinder));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to access property attribute in `GetBinder`. Is it at all possible? Or maybe there is another way how to bind a property without `ModelBinder` attribute?

Comment: Hi YuriyP, Can you share the error messages when you can't reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc in project ? Can you tell me the version of MVC and asp.net Core used in your project?

Comment: I can't reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` because that project is library which targets to `net471` and `netstandard2.1`. My web project targets to `net6.0`